# How To Do Animation in Python: Video Editor Won't Accept File

Tags: python

In Python I'm using a package called Writer that uses ffmpeg to create an animation in mp4 format.   I can write the file, the Windows video player can display it, Youtube can display it, but my video editor won't accept the file.  Other processing software will accept the file but produce nonsense.

```
        Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
        self._writer = Writer(fps=30, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)
...
        def save(self, name='test.mp4'):
        self._anim.save(name, writer=self._writer)
```

Is there some way to write an animation file in Python that produces more widely accepted output?

Comment: ffmpeg comes with a tool `ffprobe` you can use to show information about a video file -- `ffprobe test.mp4`. The output could shine some light on why the video is not accepted by some programs.

Comment: I downloaded ffprobe, unzipped, and excuted it.  The screen flashes black for an instant.  That is the only result.   Any help?

Comment: `ffprobe` is a command line tool, you have to execute it from the command line using the command `ffprobe test.mp4`. (Also if you have ffmpeg installed as you said, you also have ffprobe since it comes bundled.)

Comment: Here's what ffprobe has to say. Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Toad.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    artist          : Me
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:01:48.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1695 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 2560x1892, 1692 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler

Comment: Well it looks fine, perhaps try re-encoding the video? (https://superuser.com/a/1056632/662133)

Comment: How might one re-encode an mp4 file?

Comment: Try the link in my previous comment